# How can I loop through an array in React using the while loop and pass the index value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this reactjs while loop code

```
{(function (Arr, i, len) {
while (++i <= len) {
    const items = mainLoop.leagueOdds[0].league;
    console.log(i);

    Arr.push(<Accordion.Item eventKey={i}>
        <Accordion.Header>{items.id} {data.name} #{i}</Accordion.Header>
        <Accordion.Body></Accordion.Body>
    </Accordion.Item>)
}
return Arr;
})([], 0, 28)}`
```

with this code
`mainLoop.leagueOdds[0].league`

the array [0] is working OK,
but when i do [i] for the loop it doesnt work at all it return
`error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'league')`

I am trying to figure out how i can insert the index i for the loop so that it will loop 28 times.

Is there another work around for the while loop?

Updated* additional info.
The nested array or value that i am trying to loop is this.
[nested value array here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NTzn.png)

Comment: What is `mainLoop.leagueOdds`? Does it go up to index 28? Maybe you meant to do `i < len` not `<=` (you should increment `i` in your loop body, not in the codition, at the moment you'd be skipping index 0, or use a `for` loop which is better for loop are fixed number of times)

Comment: dear, thanks @NickParsons that is the missing. that works like magic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the  `++i` in while loop body and do  `i < len`  so you don't skip the first index .